# Reference of array value inside itself

Tags: php, arrays

I spent the last hour searching for this over the web. I need to solve a very specific issue from a block of my private project and before I throw it all out and start over on another approach, I'd like to ask it. Does anybody know it there is some way to achieve something like this:

*(Pseudocode, will fail if tried, as expected)*

```
$myArray = array(
    'a' => 'foo',
    'b' => 'bar',
    'c' => $myArray['a'].'baz'
)
```

To output this:

```
Array (
        [a] => foo
        [b] => bar
        [c] => foobaz
)
```

Anything besides assigning `$myArray['a']` to `$dummyVar` and then putting it in `$myArray['c']` again. My goal for this doesn't matter as long as I can do it. If isn't possible, I'll erase it and do it other way.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you building this array?

Comment: @DarylGill exactly as you see it in above example (with other string data, of course). I wanted to know if there is a way to reference the array inside itself before I close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work as `$myArray['a']` would actually exist when you try and reference it.

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray['a'] = 'foo';
$myArray['b'] = 'bar',
$myArray['c'] = $myArray['a'].'baz';
```

Comment: yes it would, but is there a way to do it before concluding the array declaration?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale: No, I don't think there is.

Comment: Well then, I think it's everything I needed to know :| ... thanks, guys.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Which PHP Version are you using?

Comment: @DarylGill 5.4, why? PHP7 does allow such thing?

Answer (score 1):

On my production server I am running PHP 5.6, all of the below give your expected output, though. I'd highly recommend not using the first example.. You know, as `exec` is bad.

```
$Array = array( 
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    4 => "foo",
    5 => exec("echo baz"). "foo"

);


$Array = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    4 => "foo",
    5 => ($Array[4]) . "foo"
);

$Array = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    4 => "foo",
    5 => $Array[4] . "foo"
);



echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I stand corrected with my other comment, as my PHP version is actually `5.6.10`. I tried the last two examples with no avail and unfortunately the first one does not match exactly what I wanted, being the explicit recursive reference of the array.

Comment: This only works because the first one works. **initialise the array before each and the second and third do not work** But the first does not do what the questioner wants